# Matching strings for multiple data set in Python

Tags: python

I am working on python and I need to match the strings of several data files. First I used pickle to unpack my files and then I place them into a list. I only want to match strings that have the same conditions. This conditions are indicated at the end of the string.

My working script looks approximately like this:

```
import pickle

f = open("data_a.dat")
list_a = pickle.load( f )
f.close()

f = open("data_b.dat")
list_b = pickle.load( f )
f.close()

f = open("data_c.dat")
list_c = pickle.load( f )
f.close()

f = open("data_d.dat")
list_d = pickle.load( f )
f.close()


for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        for c in list_c
            for d in list_d:
                 if a.GetName()[12:] in b.GetName(): 
                      if a.GetName[12:] in c.GetName():
                         if a.GetName[12:] in d.GetName():
                              "do whatever"
```

This seems to work fine for these 2 lists. The problems begin when I try to add more 8 or 9 more data files for which I also need to match the same conditions. The script simple won't process and it gets stuck. I appreciate your help.

Edit: Each of the lists contains histograms named after the parameters that were used to create them. The name of the histograms contains these parameters and their values at the end of the string. In the example I did it for 2 data sets, now I would like to do it for 9 data sets without using multiple loops.

Edit 2. I just expanded the code to reflect more accurately what I want to do. Now if I try to do that for 9 lists, it does not only look horrible, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: You must add a sample how how your two data files look. It's extremely weird to assume that everyone understands magical constants in your code (such as that `12`) without even getting to see the data it's operating on.

Comment: You can make a list of data files (i.e. suppose 'a' has data to be worked on, 'a' will be a list of data files ) and then iterate [read if required] and process, in this way you can process as many no. of data files in the same loops.

Comment: It is not clear how you would like to compare the 8 or 9 files.

Comment: Your code examples never defines `list_a`, `list_b`, etc.  Are they items of `list_of_lists`?

Comment: The lists contain histograms that I would like to match according to their name. That is, if the characters [12:] of a certain histogram are the same then "do something".

Comment: Does a.GetName()[12:] uniquely identify a in list_a?

Comment: Yes that is correct. And then with this identification I want to go to the other lists and match them with the tag on a.

Comment: You could use dictionaries instead of lists, or perhaps a single dict where the keys are the names, and each value is a list of histograms from all files.

Answer (score 0):

out of my head:

```
files = ["file_a", "file_b", "file_c"]
sets = []

for f in files:
    f = open("data_a.dat")
    sets.append(set(pickle.load(f)))
    f.close()

intersection = sets[0].intersection(*sets[1:])
```

EDIT: Well I overlooked your mapping to x.GetName()[12:], but you should be able to reduce your problem to set logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here a small piece of code you can inspire on. The main idea is the use of a *recursive* function.

For simplicity sake, I admit that I already have data loaded in lists but you can get them from file before :

```
data_files = [
    'data_a.dat',
    'data_b.dat',
    'data_c.dat',
    'data_d.dat',
    'data_e.dat',
]

lists = [pickle.load(open(f)) for f in data_files]
```

And because and don't really get the details of what you *really* need to do, my goal here is to found the matches on the four firsts characters :

```
def do_wathever(string):
    print "I have match the string '%s'" % string

lists = [
    ["hello", "world", "how", "grown", "you", "today", "?"],
    ["growl", "is", "a", "now", "on", "appstore", "too bad"],
    ["I", "wish", "I", "grow", "Magnum", "mustache", "don't you?"],
]

positions = [0 for i in range(len(lists))]

def recursive_match(positions, lists):
    strings = map(lambda p, l: l[p], positions, lists)
    match = True
    searched_string = strings.pop(0)[:4]
    for string in strings:
        if searched_string not in string:
            match = False
            break
    if match:
        do_wathever(searched_string)


    # increment positions:
    new_positions = positions[:]
    lists_len = len(lists)
    for i, l in enumerate(reversed(lists)):
        max_position = len(l)-1
        list_index = lists_len - i - 1
        current_position = positions[list_index]
        if max_position > current_position:
            new_positions[list_index] += 1
            break
        else:
            new_positions[list_index] = 0
            continue

    return new_positions, not any(new_positions)


search_is_finished = False

while not search_is_finished:
    positions, search_is_finished = recursive_match(positions, lists)
```

Of course you can optimize a lot of things here, this is draft code, but take a look at the [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), this is a major concept.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up using the map built in function. I realize now I should have been even more explicit than I was (which I will do in the future).

My data files are histograms with 5 parameters, some with 3 or 4. Something like this,

```
par1=["list with some values"]
par2=["list with some values"]
par3=["list with some values"]
par4=["list with some values"]
par5=["list with some values"]
```

I need to examine the behavior of the quantity plotted for each possible combination of the values of the parameters. In the end, I get a data file with ~300 histograms each identified in their name with the corresponding values of the parameters and the sample name. It looks something like,

```
datasample1-par1=val1-par2=val2-par3=val3-par4=val4-par5=val5
datasample1-"permutation of the above values"
...
datasample9-par1=val1-par2=val2-par3=val3-par4=val4-par5=val5
datasample9-"permutation of the above values"
```

So I get 300 histograms for each of the 9 data files, but luckily all of this histograms are created in the same order. Hence I can pair all of them just using the map built in function. I unpack the data files, put each on lists and the use the map function to pair each histogram with its corresponding configuration in the other data samples.

```
for lst in map(None, data1_histosli, data2_histosli, ...data9_histosli):  
  do_something(lst)
```

This solves my problem. Thank you to all for your help!

Comment: Indeed, this is a totally different problem... Did you know that you can use the `zip` builtin function instead of `map` without callback ?

Comment: Yes, I just found that out. I guess zip is like a map without the identity function. Thank you.